# Atlsd.lib Lib errors

Tags: c++

I am getting the following errors when I build in 'release' mode. Debug works fine. The use ATL is turned off in my configuration

```
Error   43  error LNK2005: "char const * const g_pszAllocFileMapName" (?g_pszAllocFileMapName@@3PBDB) already defined in atls.lib(Externs.obj)  atlsd.lib   
Error   44  error LNK2005: "char const * const g_pszKernelObjFmt" (?g_pszKernelObjFmt@@3PBDB) already defined in atls.lib(Externs.obj)  atlsd.lib   
Error   42  error LNK2005: "char const * const g_pszUpdateEventName" (?g_pszUpdateEventName@@3PBDB) already defined in atls.lib(Externs.obj)    atlsd.lib   
Error   45  error LNK2005: "class CAtlAllocator g_Allocator" (?g_Allocator@@3VCAtlAllocator@@A) already defined in atls.lib(Externs.obj)    atlsd.lib   
Error   41  error LNK2005: "unsigned int (__stdcall* ATL::g_pfnGetThreadACP)(void)" (?g_pfnGetThreadACP@ATL@@3P6GIXZA) already defined in atls.lib(atltrace.obj)    atlsd.lib   
Error   49  fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found C:\Secure\Source\cutlas\Core\Adapters\PRISAdapter\Release\PRISAdapter.exe   1
```

Any ideas

Comment: You are mixing code that was built with the Debug configuration with code that was built with the Release configuration.  Given that you think you are not using ATL, that code probably lives inside a .lib you link.  You'll need to get a Release build for that .lib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can happen that although ATL is not in use for your project some libs that you are linking against use ATL and thus have the symbols in them. The issue seems to be that you are mixing configurations - `atls.lib` is release ATL version while `atlsd.lib` is debug ATL, so thus you get duplicates. I would advise to check if libraries that you are linking against are built in the correct mode - in your Release build you should link against release versions of the external libraries, in Debug - with debug libraries. That should solve it.

Comment: Thanks. It was my own debug lib which I accidentally included in release